# Get href of link being hovered over in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperlink, hover, puppeteer

On the page I have open in Puppeteer, I have a list of coordinates. I have a loop that uses `page.mouse` to hover at the positions, and I would like to get the href of the link I am hovering over, even if it's in an iframe, like in the status popup of Chrome in the bottom right corner. I tried getting `window.status` with `page.evaluate`, but it appears that Chrome always returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are going to be over a link, you can use the `a:hover` selector.

```js
const el = await page.$('a:hover');
```

So if you want to evaluate the href you can do:

```js
const href = await.$eval('a:hover', el => el.href);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clarify that the link may be in an iframe.

Comment: Upvoting because though it doesn't fix my problem, it could fix other people's problems.